# number of links in linked list node class

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

When creating a node for a linked list it might look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class node {
 T data;
 node* next;
}
```

for a doubly linked list it might look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class node {
 T data;
 node* next;
 node* prev;
}
```

and for a BST it might look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class node {
 T data;
 node* left_child;
 node* right_child;
}
```

this can all be generalized in the following format:

```
template <class T>
class node {
 T data;
 node* links[N]; // N = 1 for linked list, N = 2 for tree or doubly linked list, etc...
}
```

What is the best way to specify N in the class ctor without using STL vectors?

Comment: I don't think the generalization is worth the loss of clarity in this case. Calling something `left_child` or `prev` instead of `links` makes the code far more understandable.

Comment: If you need to specify it in the constructor (i.e. it's known at run-time but not compile-time), then you will need (something equivalent to) a vector.

Comment: It does make the node class less understandable, yes, but with regard to the Eternally Confuzzled website http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_rbtree.aspx it makes the algorithms for insertion/deletion much easier to read

Comment: Perhaps #define statements in the tree class can define left as "0" and right as "1" or prev as "0", etc...

Comment: @rossb83: An enumeration or a set of integer constants would be much better than `#define`, since they would be scoped within the class and wouldn't break any unrelated code that tried to declare the same names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
template <class T, int N>
class node {
 T data;
 node* links[N];
};
```

and use it as:

```
node<int, 2> doubleLinkedListNode;
node<int, 1> singleLinkedListNode;
```

I however think it's too complicated, and should keep it as you had it originally. Much cleaner.